# CSS relating to the size of an element

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have an element which contains a few elements inside as follows:

[image]

When the width is above 1000px, then I want to display these 2 elements side by side such that the bar element will be aligned to the right (float right).
If the width is less than 1000px, I want to display these two elements at the center of the container as follows:

[image]

I tried using this, but it does not work:

```
var result = document.getElementsByClassName("time-target");

angular.element(result).bind('resize', function(size){
  console.log('size ' + size);
  //add the classes to the element - float right\ center - according to the size
});
```

Comment: can you show your html/css code

Comment: you can provide css property by resolution. like that:@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
    /* Styles */
}

Answer (score 2):

**Try to use `media-query` instead of js code:**

```
    @media only screen and (max-width : 1000px) {
    .element{
     //center your div
      }
    }
```

**Learn about `media-query`:**https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries 
**Attention!**
 for `media-query` you must include this `meta`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Media query is for screen not for specific element

Comment: inside you spesific element